# When you click on a thumbnail, show specific size of image on mobile + PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click on a thumbnail, show specific size of image on mobile + PC

Comment: What do you mean and? And what code? I don't know how to do this or where to start, that's why I'm asking for directions/pointers

Comment: You should seriously learn how to do this. (_use html, css and javascript_). and also check css media queries.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you need to make use of [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). With this you can change styling depending on how big your screen is.

As for the press down and hold you can do this with jQuery:

```
$('element').on('mousedown touchstart', function() { showImage() });
$('element').on('mouseup touchend', function() { hideImage() });
```

With this code you can do both mobile and desktop with the same function.